# multiple substitution and simultaneous deletion of lines from files

Tags: sed, filtering

I have a large number of files from which I want to delete lines which contain a particular set of strings.

I know `sed -i '/string1/d'` is used to do this incase you want to remove only lines containing ONE particular string, however I wanted to know what is the option for doing this incase I have a set of strings which i want to match across lines and delete those lines.

Is this possible: `sed -i '/string1|string2/d' file.txt`?

Comment: If this is yet another 'my site was hacked and I need to remove malicious JavaScript from all my files', the solution you are seeking is insufficient, and other recent questions have covered the topic in some depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape the `|`:

```
sed -i '/string1\|string2/d' file.txt
```

Note that you can also do:

```
sed -i -e '/string1/d' -e '/string2/d' file.txt
```

and in this particular case you can do:

```
sed -i '/string[12]/d' file.txt
```

(The last example is meant to illustrate that there may be many ways to manipulate the pattern to match your requirements.)

Comment: This does not allow for search patterns spanning multiple lines, though. This is notoriously tedious in `sed`, whereas Perl can do it quite naturally. Basically, `perl -0777 -pe 's/foo\nbar/baz\nquux/' file.txt`

Comment: The idiom for *slurping* a file in `sed` is quite trivial. `sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/foo\nbar/baz\nquux/' file.txt`